# Problem with Django project. AttributeError at / 'Product' object has no attribute 'Category'

Tags: python, django, web

Hello I was wondering could anyone help me with an issue I've ran into while working on a Django project. I've tried a few different things but cant seem to get it working a screenshot of the error is attached.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKTPu.png

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phoneshop:products_by_category', args=[self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phoneshop:prod_detail', args=[self.Category.id, self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Show us the code that's erroring out

Comment: Share the relevant models, view(s) and template(s).

Comment: Share also your `phoneshop/models.py` which contains `get_absolute_url()` method.

Comment: @NKSM apologies ive updated it

Comment: The `category` field on `Product` is all lowercase, you have capitalized the first character, should be: `return reverse('phoneshop:prod_detail', args=[self.category.id, self.id])`

Comment: Thank you this solved my error